# How to check if string contain list and show it in python

Tags: python, string, list

i have list:
`lst [a,b,c,d,e]`

and then the input:
`food`

i want the output :
`there is 1 d`

another input example:
`aachen`

so the output is:
`there is 2 a`
`there is 1 e`

and its doesnt matter the upppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter()` to count the occurrences of each letter, then iterate over your `lst` and output the number of times each number occurred.

```
import collections

lst = ['a','b','c','d','e']

word = 'food'

word_count = collections.Counter(word)

for letter in lst:
    count = word_count.get(letter)
    if count:
        print(f"There is {count} {letter}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python native way:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','e']
m = {}
s = input("Enter input string:")
for f in l:
  for k in range(len(s)):
    if f == s[k]:
      if f in m:
        m[f] = m[f] + 1 
      else:
        m[f] = 1

for j in m.keys():
  print(s,"has")
  print(m[j],j)
```